# Format column value in ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to angular and I have a problem. I have a value thats 1 or 0 in a value in the array.
When I show these in the table I would like to show No if its a 0 and Yes if its 1.

I have this table and Active is showing 1 or 0.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"        id="tableA">
                    <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                                       <th>ID</th>
                                                       <th>Namn</th>
                                                       <th>Active</th>
                                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                                   <tr ng-repeat="item in dRows">
                                                       <td>{{item.ID}}</td>
                                                       <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                                                       <td>{{(item.Active)}}</td>
                                   </tr>
                </tbody>
```

How to could I make it Yes and No instead?
please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator (?:) if you are using Angular version `1.1.5` or later:

```
<td>{{(item.Active == 1 ? 'Yes':'No')}}</td>
```

Another way is to use filter. 
First, add the filter to the current module

```
app.filter('YesNo', function () {
    return function (num) {
        return num === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    };
});
```

Then use it as this

```
 <td>{{(item.Active | YesNo)}}</td>
```

Comment: Great. Yes it is  :)